# Laravel Eloquent relationship function "with" and "groupBy" how use it together

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i made relationship many-to-many and its working. I need make popularity so i want use groupBy and count with query. But i dont know how i can refer to relation table rent_car.

Controller:

```
 public function popularityCar()
{

 $total_raw = DB::raw('count(*) as total');
 $cars = User::with('rentcar')
        ->where('rentcar')
        ->select('car_id', $total_raw)
        ->groupBy('car_id')           
        ->get();
 dump($cars);   
 echo $cars;
          return view('user.popularityCar',['cars' => $cars]);
}
```

Model User;

```
    public function rentcar()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cars::class,'rent_car','user_id','car_id')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('start', 'end');
}
```

Model Cars:

```
 public function caruser()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'rent_car','car_id','user_id');
}
```

So my question is how i can use groupBy and count with function "with".
I trying found it and i made somethink like i showing in my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **withCount()** method.

So your code can be like this:

```
 $cars = User::with('rentcar')
    ->withCount('rentcar')
    ->where('rentcar_count', '>', 0)
    ->get();
```

Consider **rentcar_count** field in your select list now.
Hope this helps.

**Edited:**

You're insisting to use `group by`. So update the code above to something like this:

```
 $cars = User::with('rentcar')
    ->select('car_id', \DB::raw('Count(car_id) as rentcar_count'))
    ->groupBy('car_id')           
    ->having('rentcar_count', '>', 0)
    ->get();
```

**After discussion**:

This code works fine hopefully:

```
Cars::with('caruser')
  ->withCount('caruser')
  ->where('caruser_count', '>', 0)
  ->orderBy('caruser_count', 'DESC')
  ->take(5)
  ->get();
```

Comment: but i dont like do with this way i just want learn how use groupBy and count with relationship. And i think is not the best way to resolve my problem but anyway thx for helping

Comment: @Mariusz So, you need to include `count(car_id) as rentcar_count` in your select method. Just like this!

Comment: so i need make rencar_count column ye?

Comment: @Mariusz One more thing: Replace the `where` with `having`.

Comment: but maybe is possible change it little becouse i dont want make changes in user column. Maybe is possible make join?

Comment: ,{"id":2,"name":"Admin","lastname":"Admin","email":"mariusz@gmail.com","adres":"bbb","created_at":"2017-05-10 09:46:23","updated_at":"2017-05-10 09:46:23","rentcar":[{"id":25,"name":"bmw","price":"300","description":"aa","created_at":"2017-05-11 07:04:57","updated_at":"2017-05-12 12:34:23","pivot":{"user_id":2,"car_id":25,"created_at":"2017-05-13 14:49:49","updated_at":"2017-05-13 14:49:49","start":"2017-05-13","end":"2017-05-14"}},

Comment: i have thats element when i echo  $cars = User::with('rentcar')->get(); I am interesting is possible make \DB::raw('Count(car_id) as rentcar_count')  and ->groupBy('car_id') with accessing to rentcar

Comment: and first time when i trying do it i made second variable $car_pops = DB::table('rent_car')
                  ->select('car_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('car_id')
                 ->get();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144744/discussion-between-khalil-laleh-and-mariusz).

Comment: but i got problem to display it but i know that was working